# Find the closest value within a range of cells and output cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

[image]

There are values from `F` column to `AJ` column in row 30. My input would be available in `C` column in row 30. As given in the picture, my input would be `118.45`, I would like to find the closest value to `118.45` within the range of cells from column `F` to `AJ`.

If we do it manually, I wud get `119.94` which is column `U` and row 30. Along with the value `119.94`, I would like to get the row and column reference (`U30`).  Possible to implement with some multiple functions in google sheet.

Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Vignesh. Please include a link to your sheet here, being sure to set permissions to "Anyone with the link can Edit" (not just "...can View"). That will be the easiest way for us to help you. Also, when you say you want to "find the closest value," do you mean closest whether higher or lower? Or do you mean the next highest value? Which cell should hold the formula that returns the result? Which cell should hold the formula that tells the cell reference?

Comment: Thanks much for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you only care about the absolute shortest distance to the entered number, the below should work:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+
MATCH(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
SORT(ArrayFormula({TRANSPOSE(C30:30),ABS(TRANSPOSE(C30:30)-A30)}),2,1),1,1),C30:30,0),4)
```

The idea is to create a "Table" with the list of values in the first column and the absolute difference in the second column. Sort by the smallest to the largest difference and return the first result.

Use the Match formula to find it in the row, then use Address to find the reference.

[image]

Comment: Thanks much for the response

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, VLOOKUP(C30, 
 {ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F30:AJ30), "Select *", 1)),
 {ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&
  COUNTA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F30:30), "Select Col1", 1)))))}}, 2, 0)+5, 4), 1, "")&ROW(C30), 
  SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, VLOOKUP(IF(
  INDEX(SORT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F30:30), "select Col1 where Col1>"&C30, 0), 1, 1), 1, 1)-C30>
  INDEX(SORT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F30:30), "select Col1 where Col1<"&C30, 0), 1, 0), 1, 1)-C30, 
  INDEX(SORT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F30:30), "select Col1 where Col1>"&C30, 0), 1, 1), 1, 1),
  INDEX(SORT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F30:30), "select Col1 where Col1<"&C30, 0), 1, 0), 1, 1)),
 {ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F30:AJ30), "Select *", 1)),
 {ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&
  COUNTA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F30:30), "Select Col1", 1)))))}}, 2, 0)+5, 4), 1, "")&ROW(C30))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Vignesh, you didn't reply to my comment asking for more information. So I don't know where you want results or what you mean by closest. But let's say that "closest" means "closest whether that is higher or lower." And let's say that you wanted that number in D30 and the address of that number in E30:

In D30:

`=IF((C30-INDEX(F30:30,MATCH(C30,F30:30,1)))<(C30-INDEX(F30:30,MATCH(C30,F30:30,1)+1)),INDEX(F30:30,MATCH(C30,F30:30,1)),INDEX(F30:30,MATCH(C30,F30:30,1)+1))`

In E30:

`=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMNS(A30:E30)+MATCH(A30,F30:30,0),4)`

Since the second formula references the first, you must have the first in place in order to use the second (though you can use the first independently if you wish).

AFTER OP MADE CHANGES:

New formula pairings are variations of the following (with search value in H1):

In H2:

`=IF(((H1<B2)*(H1>B28))+(H1>MAX(B2:B28))+(H1<MIN(B2:B28))>0,-1,IF(ABS(H1-INDEX(SORT(B2:B28,1,1),MATCH(H1,SORT(B2:B28,1,1),1)))<ABS(H1-INDEX(SORT(B2:B28,1,1),MATCH(H1,SORT(B2:B28,1,1),1)+1)),INDEX(SORT(B2:B28,1,1),MATCH(H1,SORT(B2:B28,1,1),1)),INDEX(SORT(B2:B28,1,1),MATCH(H1,SORT(B2:B28,1,1),1)+1)))`

In H3:

`=IF(H2=-1,H2,MATCH(H2,B:B,0))`

NOTE TO READERS: This is such a specific issue that it's doubtful anyone else will need to reproduce what was done here (i.e., find the closest value to a search value within a list of values that starts arbitrarily high, climbs higher, ends arbitrarily, starts low and climbs, and ends arbitrarily; and returning -1 if the search value falls in any of the gaps).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HKePsd4SPSNdPujnwKLvq2i8xeg5sQgy?usp=sharing

Comment: As suggested by you, i have given link of google sheet. In that sheet, i have given my requirement and also examples of what i require.Kindly provide me a way to access those functionality .help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Here in the google sheet, i have used column to accommodate the range of values, if you feel those range of values should be arranged as rows, pls go ahead and change those thing accordingly. I was not sure which way is easiest(arranging those range of values as ROWS or COLUMNS)

Comment: your help would be very much appreciated ..Thanks much

Comment: Vignesh, you've already marked @sageco's answer as the correct answer, so it seems like you no longer need help. Is this correct?

Comment: I was not aware of this . can you pls help me on this one Erik

Comment: I need your help on this one .As this one completely different from other ones and it has got some more rules as specified in the document

Comment: Will follow the rules hereafter .. was not aware of those rules of this forums.I need some more help on this one .If you want i can open a new thread and post my requirement there ..let me know pls

Comment: VIgnesh, my question wasn't meant to be punitive. It was simply unclear whether you had already received the help you needed. I looked at your sheet again. It's unclear to me what you want. I see four columns of data (B, C, D, E), but only one value you are looking for (357 in H1) and one area for results (H2:H3). Are you saying you want to run 357 through all four lists and retrieve ONE result? Four results? Please fill in your chart in H2:H3 and write a note to explain how you manually arrived at those answers. Perhaps that will help clarify things.

Comment: I have clarified my stance in the google sheet itself and it would be clear this time.Looking forward for your solution. Answers i have arrived manually are kind of closest one to the input number. I need to find the closest value irrespective of higher or lower. Thanks Erik

Comment: I assume u got the clarification u have asked for ...

Comment: Vignesh, your sheet is currently "View Only," so I can't type anything on it. Please set your permissions to "Anyone with the link can Edit."

Comment: Done !! Erik ... Sorry abt that .

Comment: I've updated my answer here to reflect formula changes in your sheet, Vignesh.

Comment: let me chk Erik ...

Comment: Awesome Mate !!!!!.. Now you have given me a solution when input ranges are in column wise. suppose if the same ranges are in row wise.. what changes need to be implemented .Will make another sheet for your easy understanding ..and another thing , it would certainly take some time to understand how you have derived the answer.. Excellent one mate...

Comment: Vignesh, this post now has many, many comments and answers. And the details continue to change to something else. It is best to start a new post when you have a new issue you'd like help with, even if it seems similar to you. If anyone searches for help in this area, they will never be able to sort through all of this to find an answer. Again, it's best to create a new post each time you have a different question or set of details.

Comment: Alright Erik ....Will post the alternative one as new post